# two host threads, two OpenGL-contexts with shared display lists (textures) and usage of cudaGLSetGLDevice

Tags: opengl, cuda

I am running two host threads that both use the same texture that is shared between their referenced OpenGL-contexts. I thought that each of these threads has to run cudaGLSetGLDevice at the very first step to:

1. bind device to current thread
2. bind device to currently made OpenGL-context

Note that thread 1 is still working when thread 2 calls cudaGLSetGLDevice. That would include that neither cudaDeviceReset has been called from thread 1 nor its OpenGL-context has been set to be done afterwards.

What I get as error-output is:

"cannot set while device is active in this process"

What can I do or what am I doing wrong?

My system consists of one NVIDIA GTX 550Ti and I'm using boost::thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to switch from runtime- to driver-api that does NOT hide context-management. Then we can create a CUDA-context for each host-thread and everything is fine, even with OpenGL-interoperability :)